# Random array of numbers without repeating - oojs practice

Tags: javascript

I'd like to practice oojs so I've written code:

```
function Randoms(c, l, h) {
    var count = c,
        min = l,
        max = h,
        nums = Array(),
        self = this;

    //returns random number from given max and min
    var getRand = function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    };

    //checks if given number is unique
    var check = function (a) {
        for (var i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (nums[i] == a) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    //makes array with random, unique numbers
    this.build = function () {

        var r = getRand();

        if (nums.length === 0) {
            nums.push(r);
        } else {
            do {
                r = getRand();
            } while (check(r));

            nums.push(r);
        }

        if (nums.length == count) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.build();
        }
    };

    //returns array
    this.get = function () {
        return nums;
    };

    //simulating constructor
    this.build();

}

var a = new Randoms(1, 1, 18);
console.log(a.get());
```

The purpose is to get array with random, unique numbers.

What do you think? Is it a good code or does it require modyfications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `check` method is inefficient for large datasets. I'd recommend using a hash instead. This will eliminate the need of iterating over the array every time you want to check if a number is there.
2. It is possible for your code to enter an infinite loop if `count` is greater than `max - min`. You need to test for this.
3. The code can be simplified a bit as well.
4. The recursion slows down the generation dramatically.

I've take then liberty of performing some optimizations: http://jsfiddle.net/FMSpG/2/

```
function Randoms(c, l, h) {
    var count = c,
        min = l,
        max = h,
        nums = {},
        out = [],
        r, len = 0;

    if (max - min < count) count = max - min;

    var getRand = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    },  check = function(a) {
        return nums[a];
    },  add = function(a) {
        nums[a] = 1;
        out.push(a);
        len++;
    };

    (function init() {
        while (len < count){
            if (len == 0) r = getRand();
            else while (check(r = getRand()));
            add(r);
        }
    })();

    this.get = function() {
        return out;
    };
}
```

And here's a jsPerf showing the huge difference in performance for large datasets:

http://jsperf.com/unique-randomization